# infopath cannot generate a form template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I recently just started at sharepoint and I've moved quite a lot however there's this error whenever I try to edit the form which is shown in the title.
Datasheet view is the one I have, and I have enabled the enterprise thing, and I have reset IE's settings to the default settings and I still face this issue.
Anyone got an idea on how to resolve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To edit the form in InfoPath, you can click “customize in InfoPath” button in the List tab in ribbon. Then publish this form after edit it in InfoPath.[image]

[image]

If I misunderstand your issue, please post some screenshot to understand your issue clearly.